# Linear Algebra Subspace question

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

Here is the following question and answer for the question.
I don't seem to quite grasp the answers or how the answers are what they are.

Requirements for subspace:

- the zero vector is in the subset
- if you add 2 elements of the subset they remain in the subset
- if you multiply any element in the subset by a constant than this is in the subset

a) Since b1 = b2, doesn't that mean that there are effectively only two vectors that define the subspace -> meaning it creates a plane in R3. Since there are no limitations all three conditions are met. Anything I missed?

b) The plane of vectors? What does that even mean. Since there is only one vector does this not only span a line?

c) All three vectors, b1, b2 and b3 must be 0 if they are to result in 0. That fulfills the zero vector requirement. b1+b2 = 0 and b1b3 = 0 (zero vector), is this not in R3?

d) Scalar multiplier of 0 fulfills the zero vector requirement.  Then I'm lost.

e) Isn't this an example of linearly independent set of vectors?

f) Lost completely.

Anyone give a light note of what they all mean! I'm lost in what they mean basically.

Comment: The numbers $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$ are *not* vectors. This seems to be a source of confusion in many of the examples - in b), for example, you are being asked to consider the the set $\{(1,b_2,b_3):b_2,b_3\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, which is indeed a plane (although it doesn't pass through the origin...). It may help to add the tuple $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ after the word "vectors" in b), c), e) and f).

Comment: As Matt said, you seem to have confused the vectors with the components $b_1, b_2, b_3$. All you need to do is just go through the terms and definitions governing this problem, you will be done. I suggest you try and do it yourself.

Comment: The other thing, which John's answer touches on, is that you should be doing things very carefully if you're learning this for the first time. So no saying things like "no limitation"; check explicitly that the zero vector is in the set, if $v$ is in the set then $\lambda v$ is in the set for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, and that if $v,w$ are in the set, then so is $v+w$. This should be fairly mechanical...what requires a little more creativity is finding a counterexample when one of these statements isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

I show the steps for the (a). 
Given the plane $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ with $b_1=b_2$

First, zero vector is contained in the set since $b_1=b_2=0$

Next, suppose there are two vectors fulfilling the equation of plane given by
$$u=(x_1,x_2,x_3) \text{ and } v=(y_1,y_2,y_3) $$
such that $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$

Now, 
$$u+v=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)$$
$u+v$ is contained in the set since $x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2$

Next,
suppose $r\in F$
$$ru=(rx_1,rx_2,rx_3)$$
$ru$ is contained in the set since $rx_1=rx_2$

Since these three conditions is satisfied, so the plane is subspace.

Answer (score -1):

(a) Consider the plane "z = 1" in $R^3$. It's not a subspace, but your argument ("there are no limitations") applies to it just as well as the one in the problem. So your argument cannot be sufficient.

(b) The set of all vectors of the form $(1, p, q)$, where $p$ and $q$ are real numbers, is a plane in 3-space. (You might call it the "x = 1" plane). They're asking if it's a subspace of $R^3$. It's not, because the vector $(0,0,0)$ is not in it.

(c) Once again your reasoning is wrong: any ONE of the three coordinates can be zero and still have $b_1 b_2 b_3 = 0$.

I worry that you may be in the wrong course, since the problems you're having are all with understanding definitions clearly, and with elementary algebra, not with linear algebra.

Comment: I think your last comment is a bit too pessimistic - these are the kinds of problems that about half of the students have at the start of the linear algebra course at my university. Most of them get over them after a couple of weeks, and go on to do perfectly well. (Anticipating possible confusion - I didn't downvote your answer.)

Comment: My own experience is more pessimistic than yours, then. I only taught linear algebra during grad school and the first 7 or 8 years of my academic life, but found that students who had problems like these often sort of caught up, but later faded. I suspect that your guess -- that OP was confusing vectors with components -- is correct, so that the confusion isn't as bad as I made it out to be. If you imagine that OP *understood* that these were components, but still wrote that stuff, you'd have to admit it looks bad...

Comment: Admittedly I don't know what happened to them many years later...but they were certainly able to solve linear algebra problems comfortably by the end of the course. I might be a little concerned if they were consistently making algebra mistakes like $b_1b_2=0\implies b_1=b_2=0$, but there's no evidence here that that was any more than a one-off error.

Comment: @John Many beginners in high mathematics are sometimes lost in the dark . To establish the OP is "in the wrong" course because he has *now* some misunderstandings that can probably be more or less easily and deeply corrected is, besides of pessimistic, even a little demeaning and unduely discouraging. I think it is both good and justifying that you only taught during grad school.

Comment: @John I saw afterwards that it was indeed components of a vector, I am slightly tired at the moment. Also the best of teachers encourage people, not dismay them. In any case your pessimistic views will not deter my will for wanting to learn linear algebra. If you said that to someone with not a strong will you could potentially ruin a future career, maybe you already have.

Comment: I *want* folks to learn math. Many students get lost when they miss some basic stuff, and then cannot progress in some later course. Suggesting that they solidify their basics is the best thing I can do. In *this* case I failed to read your mind and understand the nature of your confusion; for that I'm sorry. But if indeed you had not had *that* misunderstanding, might my advice not have been good? I didn't say "quit math". I said "solidify the basics." [BTW, I still teach, at Brown U., albeit in CS, and get quite strong student evaluations. I just haven't taught *Linear Algebra* in a while.]